# Paytm All-in-one Sdk in laravel system error

Tags: php, laravel, paytm

Paytm PHP SDK with laravel its work on my localhost but when um make a request from my AWS server it shows me system error. um test it with my localhost server it shows me the Paytm page. um using production credentials of Paytm

```
$paytmParams['body'] =[
    'requestType'=>'Payment',
    'mid'=> config('paytm.merchant_id'),
    'websiteName'=> config('paytm.merchant_website'),
    'orderId'=> $orderId,
    'callbackUrl'=> 'https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID='.$orderId,
    'txnAmount' => [
        'value'=> number_format($cartData->total, 2, '.', ''),
        'currency'=> config('app.currency')
    ],
    'userInfo'=>[
        'custId' => 'CUST_'.$request->user()->id,
        'mobile'=> $request->user()->phone_no,
    ],
];
$checksum = \paytm\paytmchecksum\PaytmChecksum::generateSignature(json_encode($paytmParams["body"], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES), config('paytm.merchant_key'));
$paytmParams["head"] = [
    'signature'=> $checksum,
    'channelId'=> config('paytm.app_channel')
];
$post_data = json_encode($paytmParams, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
$url = "https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/api/v1/initiateTransaction?mid=".config('paytm.merchant_id')."&orderId=".$orderId;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: What's your error?

Comment: its say system error. when um upload it on ubuntu server. but my localhost server its work fine.